# If $\lim{f_{n}}=f$ on $\mathcal{C}^{1}([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ means that $f_{n}\to f$ and $f'_{n}\to f$ uniformly

Tags: uniform-convergence

Let $\mathcal{C}^{1}([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ the vectorial space of functions $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ of class $\mathcal{C}^{1}$, with the norm $\vert\vert f\vert\vert=\displaystyle\sup_{x\in[a,b]}(\vert f(x)\vert+\vert f'(x)\vert)$. Show that if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{f_{n}}=f$ on $\mathcal{C}^{1}([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ means that $f_{n}\to f$ and $f'_{n}\to f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$.

I know that if $f_{n}$ converges uniformly to $f$, then $\vert\vert f_{n}-f\vert\vert=\displaystyle\sup_{x\in[a,b]}\{\vert f_{n}(x)-f(x)\vert+\vert f'_{n}(x)-f'(x)\vert\}$
$\leq\displaystyle\sup_{x\in[a,b]}\vert f_{n}(x)-f(x)\vert+\displaystyle\sup_{x\in[a,b]}\vert f'_{n}(x)-f'(x)\vert=0$,

Therefore, $\vert f_{n}(x)-f(x)\vert=0$ and $\vert f'_{n}(x)-f'(x)\vert=0$,follow that $f_{n}\to f$ and $f'_{n}\to f'$ uniformly. Is this correct?? Regards!

Comment: No, your proof is not correct. You have several mistakes.  The part that starts with "I know that if" and ends with $0$ is completely wrong; all of it.

Comment: Why?, Consider the sequence  $a_n = \sup |f_{n}(x) - f(x) |$  where the supremum is taken over all  $x \in M$ . Then  $f_n$  converges to $f$   uniformly if and only if $a_n$  tends to $0$.

Comment: That is correct. But you made the sequence equal to zero, identically, which is one error. The other error is that you deduced from the uniform convergence of $f_n$ something about the sequence of the derivatives. That is your second error. Thirdly, you did not use the hypothesis given, namely, that $f_n$ tends to $f$ in the space $C^1$. That is your third error.

Comment: Ok, I see. You can give me a help to solve this thanks!